# Use multiple project in c# source generator

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a C# source generator where I need to reference source files (.cs) that are in another project in the solution. Is there a clean way to do this ?

Here is my context for clarity.

I'm building a Blazor webapp where I have a server and a client.
I use attribute routing to set the url in the webapi.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/clients/{id}", Name = "Client")]
public async Task<ClientViewModel> GetById(int id)
{
    var client = await _clientLogic.GetById(id);
    return _clientViewLogic.ToViewModel(client);
}
```

I'd like to avoid

- On the server, having to use the route name to build an url. As I don't have any compile check on the route name and could have error if I change the name and forget to update a call.
- On the client, having to directly use the raw url as I don't have access to the server context to build it.

Instead I'd like to use something like this

```cs
var url = GetClientUrl(clientId);
```

This should be easily doable with a source generator that would convert

```cs
[Route("api/clients/{id}", Name = "Client")]
```

into

```cs
public string GetClientUrl(string id)
{
    return $"api/clients/{id}";
}
```

The problem is that as I'm working with Blazor I need to place the code into a **Shared** project that is referenced by both my **Server** project and **Client** project. But if I add the source generator to the **Shared** project, then I only have the **compilation context** of this project and I can't access the Route attributes inside my **Server** project to build my functions.

So my full question is, is there a way to access my Server compilation context from a source generator linked to my Shared project ?

One way I see to fix this is to ignore the compilation context provided by the source generator, and create a new one based on all the projects in the solution by hardcoding the path or something. This should work but doesn't feel very clean.

Comment: Why don't you use something purpose-built for this like swagger? It doesn't sound like a trivial task.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Swagger was able to generate code for net5. Could be usefull for a production project thanks. But in this case I'm working a on personal project to learn blazor and new features of net5. So I try to do my own implementation.

Comment: @cpaulus did you ever find out a way to reference both compilation contexts of the Server and Shared projects?

Comment: I did it manually. My source generator looks for a .json file containing the path of the project where the routes are. Then I manually load each .cs file to extract the routes and generate my code. I used the method  CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(file) to manually load the cs file.

Comment: @cpaulus Thanks for the response. If you manage to find some time, would you mind sharing a small example of what that implementation looks like please?

Comment: @Andrew here it is https://gist.github.com/CyrilPaulus/c9a66c033f593bad30d6bfc0f34fa590
keep in mind that it was hardcoded for my use case. A little bit of work will probably be needed to make it more generic. But it should give you a starting point.

Comment: @cpaulus I'm wondering: in AutoRouteConfig.json you had to put full path or relative?

Comment: If it's supposed to generate part of a shared api, you should have placed an interface of the api in a shared location anyway. I use my SG in a project and generate request logic on client and controllers on the server, with different code template supplied as AdditionalText.